# Reading a configuration Value from YAML in Micronaut

Tags: yaml, micronaut

How to read a value from application.yml in my Micronaut project? I can clearly see annotation is resolved to proper value (true in this case), but it is not applied to the variable (stays as default false). I've tried using @Value and @ConfigurationProperties

[image]

Comment: See the project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/filiard.  The property at https://github.com/jeffbrown/filiard/blob/ed01026d28158e8ba8e8e68df964fc1a1cb2f82f/src/main/java/filiard/DemoController.java#L9-L10 is being initialized with the value from https://github.com/jeffbrown/filiard/blob/ed01026d28158e8ba8e8e68df964fc1a1cb2f82f/src/main/resources/application.yml#L8-L9.

Comment: In your example works as expected. It doesn't work in my case, because I create instance of "FeatureToggleService" in another class. How to make it, so this value is injected when the object is created elsewhere?

Comment: "How to make it, so this value is injected when the object is created elsewhere?" - See the FlagHelper at https://github.com/jeffbrown/filiard/commit/f6f704fb95d7821919748bb41968f87d11cee07b.  If you are creating the instance yourself by doing something like `new FlagHelper()` then `@Value` is not expected to be relevant.

Answer (score 3):

In a comment the OP has indicated that they are doing `new FeatureToggleService()`.  Creating your own instance of the object is the problem.  Instead of using `new`, let the DI container create and manage the instance.  If you do, then `@Value` will be relevant.

See https://github.com/jeffbrown/filiard/blob/f6f704fb95d7821919748bb41968f87d11cee07b/src/main/java/filiard/DemoController.java and https://github.com/jeffbrown/filiard/blob/f6f704fb95d7821919748bb41968f87d11cee07b/src/main/java/filiard/FlagHelper.java for a working example.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:**

Based on additional information this is **not** the correct answer!!!

As pointed out, `@Value` can be private, but Micronaut advices against it.

> Short answer, it is because it is `private`. **Wrong**
>
> From the documentation:
>
> > The @Value annotation accepts a string that can have embedded placeholder values (the default value can be provided by specifying a
> > value after the colon : character). Also try to avoid setting the
> > member visibility to private, since this requires Micronaut Framework
> > to use reflection. Prefer to use protected.
>
> Also, consider using `@Property` instead of `@Value`. **Still valid**
> https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/#valueAnnotation

*NOTE:*

The Micronaut framework does not inspect a manually created instance, even if it is instantiated in a `@Factory`, unlike other frameworks.

Comment: This is not it, still resolved to "false"

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/Tyfl3iV.png
It worked for a moment, but after rebuilding its back to false

Comment: How is the class being created (ex: `@Singleton`)?

Comment: We express a preference that you not use `private` for performance reasons, but `@Value` does work on private fields.

Comment: It is created as a private field in another class with "new FeatureToggleService()"

Comment: "It is created as a private field in another class with "new FeatureToggleService()" - That is fine.  It isn't a good idea because initializing the value requires runtime reflection, but it is supported.  However, the fact that you are using `new` to create the instance is the problem.  In order for `@Value` to be relevant, the DI container needs to manage the instance for you.

Comment: I know this answer has some upvotes, but I really don't think the cause of the problem is related to `private`.  See comments I left under the question with links to a working solution.